# From a combination list, Insert tuples Index[0] and Index[1] into a function

Tags: python, tuples, range, combinations, python-itertools

The objective is to create a series of new columns by inserting index[0] and index[1] from the different tuples into the CHOICES function and the DF function at the end of the code.

the problem is that I´m only getting the first tuple (10 & 11)  inside the function and there fore I´m only getting 1 column into the data frame (sma_10 & sma_11)instead of the 30 or more new columns

On the second part of the code,  3 examples on how the index must be plug into the functions using the first 2 tuples (10,11), (10,12) and the last tuple (48,49)

What I’m doing wrong? Any ideas, clues or comments more than appreciated

Original Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations

b = list(combinations(range(10, 50),2))

x = b[0]
y = b[1]

print((b))
print(list(x))
print((y[1]))

conditions = [df[f'sma_{x[0]}'] > df[f'sma_{x[1]}'],
             df[f'sma_{x[0]}'] < df[f'sma_{x[1]}']]

choices = [1, -1]

df[f'sma_{x[0]} & sma_{x[1]}'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

Second part

**Tuple (10,11)**

```
conditions = [df[f'sma_{10}’] > df[f'sma_{11}'],
                 df[f'sma_{10}’] < df[f'sma_{11}']]
    
    choices = [1, -1]
    
    df[f'sma_{10} & sma_{11}’] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

**Tuple (10,12)**

```
conditions = [df[f'sma_{10}’] > df[f'sma_{12}’],
                 df[f'sma_{10}’] < df[f'sma_{12}’]]


choices = [1, -1]

df[f'sma_{10} & sma_{12}’] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

**Tuple (48,49)**

```
conditions = [df[f'sma_{48}’] > df[f'sma_{49}’],
                 df[f'sma_{48}’] < df[f'sma_{49}']]
    
    choices = [1, -1]
    
    df[f'sma_{48} & sma_{49}’] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

Comment: maybe it would help telling what errors you get?

Comment: the problem is that I´m only getting the first tuple (10 & 11) inside the function and there fore I´m only getting 1 column into the data frame (sma_10 & sma_11) instead of the 30 new columns